# Burninate? Great [success]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I just stumbled across the [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success) tag, which looks like a pile of execrable garbage. How can one be an expert in success unless you are Jon Skeet?

It's a meta-tag, doesn't add any value to any question its tagged on, and it should be a fairly easy job because there are only 270 questions tagged [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success).

Sure, the question might be talking about a problem in a success case, but that should be obvious from the question itself, and doesn't really add value when trying to search for it. Don't we all secretly hope that every bit of code we write is a success?

Comment: [tag:success] adds little relevant information to a question that can't already be covered within the body; it should be burninated.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773/17034

Comment: No, we don't need the tag [tag:success].  I've successfully removed it from one question that had only the [tag:success] tag — it now sports a nice [tag:angularjs] tag instead. There are a number of old (2008, 2009 era) questions about success of projects in one shape or another. Such questions which aren't already closed should usually be closed with 'too broad' or 'primarily opinion based'. Most of the others should simply successfully lose their [tag:success] tag, but many of them need other (often major) surgery to bring them up to some semblance of an OK standard for a question.

Comment: @royhowie The purpose of tags is not to add information not already in the body; it is to _summarize_ the body extremely briefly.

Comment: As for success, then yes, I do.

Comment: It is an un[success]ful tag

Comment: The other purpose of success is to help with searching and filtering. It seems unlikely that anyone would select [success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success) as a favorite or hidden tag.

Comment: @HelloGoodbye Tags exist to categorize questions, not to summarize them. The number of [questions that are summarized by their tags](http://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/2359271) could probably be counted on the fingers of one hand. And in many cases, tags allow for some context not to be explicitly stated in the body; which DMBS, which version of a library, etc.

Comment: I want to [tag:complete] this...

Comment: burn it , burn it with fire!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm, yes it looks like it is, though I did not see it when posting, but the main question is - why that [success] was still in use after 4 months  after posting that question.

Comment: @Air Fair enough.

Comment: @dav Burnination complete.

Comment: [Blacklisting is the key to success.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297838/blacklisting-is-the-key-to-success)

Comment: I love Jon Skeet jokes. He's basically the Chuck Norris of Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This tag has been completely burninated.

- [ajax-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-success) now has 153 questions, and someone more familiar with it should give it a tag wiki.
- I also created a tag [magento-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento-success) for those questions about the magento success page. There are 11 questions with this tag.

The tag will automatically be deleted at the next tag cleanup, which I believe happens at 0300 UTC.

Answer (score 36):

We don't need no replacement for [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success), nor the tag as-is.
The tag itself is useless (*what* is or isn't successful?), and as [Hans Passant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/u/17034) [noted in another answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773), building the product of two bags of tags is rarely a good idea, especially if the base tags stay.

Comment: Maybe it should be renamed to [tag:ajax-success] (since it's a method in ajax, and doing so will mostly stop mis-tagging)?

Comment: @cybermonkey: The mistagging identified is using the tag at all, not choosing the wrong tag.

Comment: [Blacklisting is the key to success.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297838/blacklisting-is-the-key-to-success)

Answer (score 3):

As the related tags hint, `success()` is the name of a method on the return value of `jQuery.ajax()`. It's currently deprecated in favor of more standard [promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/promise) methods, but still in use by some folks using or just used to older versions of jQuery.

Apparently it's also a bit of a *thing* in Magento.

[image]

Comment: Yes, the jQuery/AJAX related usage seems like an important topic.  Maybe a cleanup and rename to [jquery-success]?

Comment: `.success()` is deprecated in jQuery, so I'm not thrilled at the idea of a tag for it. Maybe a combination of [tag:jquery] [tag:promise] (or a new tag for that combination) would be better?

Comment: Promise already exists as a tag, @kevin.

Comment: Right @Shog9, I couldn't tell if you were advocating retagging [tag:jquery] + [tag:success] questions as [tag:jquery] + [tag:promise], or if we are going to want to start the disambiguation process early by creating something like [tag:javascript-promise] (or use [tag:jquery-deferred], the jQuery equivalent).

Comment: Now that [tag:success] has been burninated, can it be blacklisted like [tag:error] has been?