# synonym request: deleting in SQL

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-process

There are two tags that refer to deleting rows in SQL:

[sql-delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-delete), described as:

> The DELETE statement removes one or more records from a table. A subset may be defined for deletion using a condition, otherwise all records are removed. Some DBMSs, like MySQL, allow to delete rows from multiple tables with one DELETE statement (this is sometimes called multi-table DELETE).

And [delete-row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/delete-row), described as:

> The deletion can be achieved by using the DELETE statement of the SQL language.

I don't have enough rep in either tag to propose either as a synonym of the other, but it seems as though they obviously are. Could one of the mods, or users with enough rep in those tags start the ball rolling?

Comment: I'm not so sure about this. I did a cursory glance over `delete-row` and it appears that a lot of those have nothing to do with SQL.  There would need to be significant clean-up before these should be made synonyms.

Comment: @bluefeet alternatively, all SQL-related questions could be migrated to `sql-delete` (to follow the convention of `sql-insert` and `sql-update`, and a new description could be written for this tag

Comment: My first thought about the delete-row tag is it was related to html and javascript and not sql.

Comment: @JoeW mine too - until I read the tag's excerpt

Answer (score 43):

[image]

That describes quite well what happened with these tags.  Back in August 2014, users set out to set the New Standard and retagged [sql] + [delete] questions to [sql] + [sql-delete].  Same treatment on [sql] + [insert].  Producing bizarre tautologies that questioners don't actually like to use.

So now we have:

- 168 questions tagged [sql] + [sql-delete]
- 164 questions tagged [sql-delete]
- 574 questions tagged [sql] + [delete]
- 486 questions tagged [sql] + [sql-insert]
- 627 questions tagged [sql-insert]
- 1954 questions tagged [sql] + [insert]

Folks, this is not useful.