# Are [transform] and [css-transforms] the same thing?

Tags: discussion, tags

If the tag wiki's are accurate, both [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) and [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) refer to [CSS transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform). It seems [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) is the more-popular tag with almost 4 times as many questions, but not all of the questions tagged refer to CSS transforms. It's also being use for algorithms, matrices, and other things that aren't CSS.

Here is a breakdown as of this writing.

- [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) has 685 questions.
- [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) has 2671 questions.

  - Of those in [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform), only 1012 are also tagged [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and/or [css3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css3).

Currently, [css-backface-visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-backface-visibility) is a synonym for [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms), and [transform-origin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform-origin) (a CSS tag), had been proposed as a synonym for [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform). Also the content of the [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) tag wiki is much better than the other as far as CSS transforms goes.

As they currently are, I think these two tags can be consolidated. But should a tag named [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) exclusively mean CSS transforms? Less than half of the questions tagged with it are referring to CSS (based on the related CSS tags). I'm not sure CSS transforms even existed when [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) was created, and the oldest questions tagged with it do not relate to CSS. It seems like the word "transform" may be a little too broad to mean anything specific.

Comment: "It seems like the word 'transform' may be a little too broad to mean anything specific." This.

Comment: I have now made [transform-origin] a synonym of [css-transforms].

Comment: @BoltClock: [transform-origin] is really a CSS tag? Curious...

Comment: @Deduplicator: I could run a merge instead. [transform-origin] does not appear to have ever been used with a non-CSS question.

Comment: @BoltClock: That has my vote.

Comment: OK, so about three [transform-origin] questions were not CSS related. The rest are. I've retagged the outliers and run a merge *without* synonymizing them.

Comment: There are 655 questions that are tagged [css] + [transform] and 444 questions that are tagged [css] + [css-transforms].  These combinator tags do a [lousy job](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773/17034) of categorizing questions.

Comment: All [css-transforms] are [transforms], but as you saw, the reverse is most definitely not true. The [transforms] tag-wiki is simply a lie.