# Trogdorbots, [transform] and burninate!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

After reading through [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293832/are-transform-and-css-transforms-the-same-thing), its comments and some questions tagged with [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) I feel like this tag shouldn't exist on this site as it is too vague in meaning. Let's go through the criteria for burnination:

---

**Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied and is unambiguous?**
In my opinion, it's basically entirely ambiguous. It doesn't really add information besides that some kind of transformation is taking place which really could mean anything (see last criteria).

**Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**
No, not by default. There some Photoshop-Questions that would qualify for off-topic but the big majority is definitely on topic.

**Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**
No, it doesn't.

**Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
Not at all. A lot of questions should instead be tagged with [data-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-transform) (which should probably be renamed to *data-transform**s***) or [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) but even though the tag wiki of [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) <s>makes</s> made it look like the two tags are basically the same, they are really not. Proof: 2,868 of 4,443 (64%) questions are tagged with [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) but not with [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css).

You will find questions about [table-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56904663/convert-access-transform-pivot-query-to-sql-server), [Java Transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1384802/java-how-to-indent-xml-generated-by-transformer), [Operational Transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043165/operational-transformation-library), a lot of [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13329125/removing-transforms-in-svg-files) and [many other disconnected topics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform%2B-css%2B-svg).

---

I think this tag should be burninated as it does not serve any purpose. No person could possibly be using this tag to find anything as the result is a pile of random questions from all sorts of different areas of knowledge. I propose the following action plan:

1. Re-tag all [1,510 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform+css+-svg) who have both [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) but don't include [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg) with [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) (instead of [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform))
2. Re-tag all [155 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform+svg+-css) who have both [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg) and [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) but don't include [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) with [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms) (instead of [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform))
3. Manually retag all [65 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform+css+svg) who have [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css) and [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) with either [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) or [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms) (instead of [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform))
4. Retag all questions which are about transforming data to [data-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-transform)
5. Kill [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform)

**EDIT:** I just realized [transformation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transformation) is basically the same dumpster-fire minus the [css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css)-questions.

**EDIT 2:** As currently [nothing is being burned](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/) maybe we could start working on this!

Comment: "Coordinate and other transformations. You probably want a more specific tag like [css-transforms]." is the excerpt. Says a lot already IMO. (I was thinking coordinate-transforms as well at first, but that's probably because that is what I am doing these days.)

Comment: Please hold off on removing the tag from questions without replacement unless there is a clear consensus from the community. A moderator will be able to help you out as to the specifics.

Comment: @jhpratt How much clearer do you want the consensus to become? There is not a single person that has brought forward an argument against the retags?

Comment: There are currently 5 downvotes on your post. The point isn't that there hasn't been a presented argument against, it's that _it's not solely up to you_.

Comment: @jhpratt Well that is what review queues are there for, right? If the approval of more privileged and experienced community members is given, I assume my edit was of value to the community.

Comment: My point is that you're going through a ton of old questions, bumping them to the front page, presumably without looking too much at the question itself (just looking at the tags). That's what burnination is for. There are thousands of questions tagged with this; there's no way in hell you could do it all yourself.

Comment: @jhpratt Just to clarify I didn't "remove the tag without replacement".  The question was tagged with both [transform] and [css-transform] when it was clearly about the ladder

Comment: @jhpratt How do you propose to edit all questions under task 3. without bumping them?

Comment: Again, you need to wait for consensus before doing so. Looking through your suggested edit history, it also appears you singlehandedly burninated [rule-of-thumb] and [inventions], and I can find nothing showing you've conferred with a trusted user beforehand as is required by the [burnination criteria] (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: @jhpratt I might be wrong here but I assume that there is no need in raising a request on meta for a tag with two questions. If this is against any rule I am not aware of please link it so I can educate myself.

Comment: You removed [rule-of-thumb] from 13 questions by my count. I didn't look too much into [inventions], if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: @jhpratt [inventions] had two questions and the removal of [rule-of-thumb] wasn't my idea: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350397/burninate-rules-tags

Comment: [rule-of-thumb] is not [rules]. If you want to burninate a tag, go through the process _for each tag_. That is how the process works.

Comment: @jhpratt I was talking about the comments of that post

Comment: Per the burnination guidelines, if a tag has less than 50 questions (as that did), you need to confer with a trusted user. The user that brought it up has 4k rep, not 20k.

Comment: Per the [editing guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260246/7910454) I should `Edit tags to match the question`. If I see a question that uses [transform] when it is about [css-transform] I feel obligated to fix that mistake.

Answer (score 6):

This should be fairly easy to handle—as a [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request), at least. The CSS and SVG retags are no-brainers, but there are a substantial number of questions tagged [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) that relate to other specific uses of some 'transform' functionality. Those ~3k questions should be assessed for some other commonality, in case we can have the [transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/transform) tag simply renamed and re-described instead of simply burninated. I can tell you as someone involved with the community burnination process that a tag with several thousand questions is not likely to be community-burninated any time soon.

Comment: People don't care - they will use `transform` for their css-questions even if the tag wiki is literally: "DO NOT USE FOR CSS-TRANSFORM"

Comment: @MiXT4PE Maybe you missed the part of my answer that suggested renaming it to something else. It's much less likely people will use [tag:coordinate-transforms] for CSS transforms, for example (or another specific non-CSS/SVG use of transforms).

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry. I actually missed that. Well I think it will be hard to find any real commonality in the remaining 3k but we could try indeed

Comment: Is it possible to blacklist combinations? Like [css] and [transform] aren't allowed together or automatically get retagged after posting

Comment: @MiXT4PE It's possible I'm sure but I doubt SO would go that route. It's a heavy handed approach that could be invalidated in the future -- much better to just clean up tags the normal way.

Comment: A common occurence, at least on the first page appears to be using [tag:transform] as synonym for conversion (aka transformation)