# svg-transform has to change somehow

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

[svg-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transform) has [8 questions associated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transform) and I think we should  do one of the following:

1. Rename it to [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms) so the naming is consistent with [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms)
2. Make it a synonym of [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms) as it is basically inline-CSS-transforms anyway
3. Suggestion by [Robert Longson](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1038015/robert-longson): Make it a synonym of [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg)

I would suggest 2. or 3. to reduce [the confusion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387014/trogdorbots-transform-and-burninate) around this topic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've renamed the tag to [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms).

As [Robert Longson says](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/392568/), it is not appropriate to synonymize [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms) and [css-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/css-transforms), since they are different things.

I am not convinced that it makes sense to merge [svg-transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transforms) into [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), so I've not done that.

Comment: Thank you! Btw: Shouldn't [css-transform] also be a synonym of [css-transforms]?

Comment: @leonheess The [[tag:css-transform]] tag does not exist.

Comment: Yes, I know, but it used to. It was [css-transform] for a while and at some point got renamed to  [css-transforms] which is why old Meta discussions are referencing the old [css-transform] which is basically a dead link now.

Comment: I don't see any evidence that the [[tag:css-transform]] tag was ever renamed to [[tag:css-transforms]]. If [[tag:css-transform]] ever did exist, it must have been manually removed and renamed to [[tag:css-transforms]] by users editing the questions. Either way, I don't see  any reason why a synonym is required if the tag doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: Well, its not for me to decide but it definitively was renamed at some point. The advantage of such a synonym would be no more dead tag-links in old questions. The disadvantages would be none.

Comment: @leonheess Fair enough; synonym created.

Comment: Thank you! I also found [data-transform], [instance-transform] and [matrix-transform] which probably also should be renamed respectively. There are many more [*-transform] like [hough-transform] I don't have a deep enough understanding of to suggest a rename.

Comment: I also keep finding tags that were renamed but their old name is not a synonym. It seems to be a reoccurring problem. Example: [flipkart] was renamed to [flipkart-api]

Answer (score 2):

SVG transforms are different from CSS transforms. The syntax is different.

- CSS transforms, like CSS in general, has mandatory units for non-zero values
- SVG transforms do not allow units.

Now, SVG 2 does map SVG transforms to CSS transforms (i.e., an SVG transform has the effect of a CSS transform, but it still doesn't change the syntax that you use to write that SVG transform).

[svg-transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg-transform) could be just a synonym of [svg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg), of course.

Comment: Thanks for the insight! Also a possibility I would be happy with