# If it has tag A and tag B, should it also have tag A-B?

Tags: discussion, tags, editing-help

I just stumbled upon this while checking edits and wasn't sure how to deal with it.

There's a question that is tagged with tags `A` and `B`, but there's a more specialised tag that's the combination of both `A-B`.

Should I edit the question and add the tag `A-B`? For me, this is equal to "Should I accept edits that add such a tag?"

Just to be clear, `A-B` is a valid tag for the question. It is the only modification of the edit.

Comment: Not necessarily.  See this example with [excel, vba, and excel-vba](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295302/is-this-implication-true-excel-vba-excel-vba).  And that seems a bit unnecessary to "fix" unless the post needs other improvements.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293762/synonym-request-deleting-in-sql/293773

Comment: @HansPassant so you say this is probably a result of tags that shouldn't exist anyway? Is that an answer?