# Split the [merge]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-disambiguation

## TL;DR

My proposal is to split [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge), replace it with subject-related tags and burninate.

Answering the [burninate manual](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191):

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? No, no.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? Yes, each [particular-subject-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/particular-subject-merge) is on-topic.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? No, it confuses user about the post contents.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? As I show further, not at all.

## Update

Why [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) is good and [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git)[command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command)[merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) is bad: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/266254/2790048

## Long story <s>short</s> long.

### Top questions

The tag [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) is currently used on several unrelated categories of questions:

1. Merging in version control systems:

   - Git merge, where a specified [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) exists. This is the majority of [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge)-tagged questions.
   - Subversion merge: [Why am I getting tree conflicts in Subversion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/738367/)
   - Mercurial merge: [How to correctly close a feature branch in Mercurial?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237222/)
2. Merging arrays and other collections [array-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/array-merge):

   - Javascript [How to merge two arrays in Javascript and de-duplicate items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/)
   - C# [Merging dictionaries in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/294138/)
3. Merging (which is actually concatenating) strings: [How can 2 strings be concatenated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7201341/how-can-2-strings-be-concatenated-in-r)
4. Merging entities in JPA: [JPA EntityManager: Why use persist() over merge()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069992/)
5. Merging data in a database with SQL: [sql-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-merge) [Insert, on duplicate update in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1109061/)
6. Merging files: [filemerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filemerge), [merge-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-file) [Merge / convert multiple PDF files into one PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2507766/)
7. Merging source code: [Any decent text diff/merge engine for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/138331/)
8. Merging something in [android-layout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layout): [How to get RelativeLayout working with merge and include?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2316465/)
9. Functional programming (it seems to me): [Adding code to a javascript function programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9134686/adding-code-to-a-javascript-function-programatically)

And that is just the first two pages of most upvoted questions. These questions were viewed tens of thousands of times. Why is this tag still in such disorder?

### New questions

Now, let's look at the [new questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge?sort=newest&pageSize=30) on [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge):

1. Merging in geospatial information software: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30979213/
2. [bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash): [count lines with different conditions using awk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30975398/)
3. Merging audio and video streams:

   - [android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android)  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966203/
   - [ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ios) [Merge audio/video when audio duration is less than video duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30914424/)
4. Merging [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) data: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30937813/
5. Merging [ontology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ontology)'es in [owl-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/owl-api): [How to properly merge 2 ontologies with OWL API 4 or 3.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888449/)
6. To be continued.

Isn't this too mush for one tag?

### Usage attempts

Say, I want to understand merging in Git better. I'm a rational person, so I open the [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge) top voted questions. But I have no idea about [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) questions, which are also good. Does the tag help me find them?

Now, I want to know about merging in SQL. I open the [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge), which has 8697 questions and not [sql-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-merge), which has just 54. Guess what I see? Almost nothing on my topic.

By the time you read this post half of the new questions will probably be deleted. This is because their authors just picked the first tags that came at sight; maybe they were also unattentive to the question contents. The only thing that [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) allows me to do is filter questions, written with less attention than required. Wow!

Comment: Hey. Not enough pun!

Comment: Don't worry, some good puns should emerge from the comments.

Comment: If you want to know about merging in SQL you use the  tag [sql] _and_ the tag [merge]... It's kinda how tagging works, ever-increasing exactness. As a small bonus no one needs to retag 8k questions to get exactly the same result; though it might be worth merging [sql-merge] back into [merge] and ensuring that they're all tagged [sql].

Comment: @Ben So, to know about [tag:git-filter-branch] command I should search by [tag:git] + [tag:filter] + [tag:branch], right?

Comment: @StuperUser ...some good puns should e`merge` ... i see what you did there.

Comment: No, you'd use the tag [git-filter-branch] @Nick, which seems to be the accepted way. I think you're mistaking me; the tags you're proposing are perfectly reasonable. You're not taking into account what people have been using for years, and therefore what comes naturally to them or the fact that there's 8,000 questions. It'll literally never happen without database access and even then you're fighting the world as people will be using the thing that comes naturally.

Comment: @Ben it seems to me that if [tag:merge] is prohibited and well-documented [tag:fizz-merge], [tag:buzz-merge] and [tag:bar-merge] are available, it will come naturally to users which tag to use in the further questions. If there's no appropriate tag, then the question will probably be ok without it.

Comment: @Ben: [please have a look on SQL INSERT](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/293762/synonym-request-deleting-in-sql/293773#293773) :) others are welcome too..

Comment: @NickVolynkin: I wanted to point out that there are some well-known examples of how people as a community seem to be unable to decide on a uniform way of tagging cases, where some terms have ambiguous meanings when they are used separately.

Comment: It's not 'cause tags are ambiguous thought @quet; it's as xkcd has it; some people try to enforce a different standard, which fails to gain traction. In the case of SQL because it doesn't use the actual keywords. It's all a moot point anyway; no one's going to manually retag 8k questions...

Comment: @quetzalcoatl thank you, I see your point. Such operations can be harmful when stopped halfway.

Comment: Is the word "split" the comedic element in the title?

Comment: @BillWoodger it took me a day to understand that it's actually a pun. But I was serious at the time of asking.

Comment: @nicael consider the proximity, and meanings, of the words split and merge. OK, turns out it was unintended, but completely sufficient.

Comment: @Bill I'm unsure if nicael is actually complaining about the lack of pun or being sarcastic about the surplus of pun. :)

Comment: Well, I was lulled by the uncontested following comments :-)

Comment: sub[merge] this tag underwater

Comment: While we're at it, should we merge the [split] string? :)

Comment: @BhargavRao punderwater.

Comment: Ugh, came across this problem today.

Answer (score 19):

How it should be done in my opinion:

[merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) should be replaced with subject-related tags where it's reasonable, then deleted from others and forbidden forever.

It seems to me that if [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge) is prohibited and well-documented [fizz-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fizz-merge), [buzz-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/buzz-merge) and [bar-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bar-merge) are available, it will come naturally to users which tag to use in the further questions. If there's no appropriate tag, then the question will probably be ok without it.

1. VCS-related:

   1. Git: replace with [git-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git-merge)
   2. Mercurial: replace with [hg-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hg-merge)
   3. SVN: [svn-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svn-merge).
2. SQL: [sql-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql-merge)
3. Various data structures:

   1. Not language-specific algorithms: maybe create new [data-structures-merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-structures-merge) or [data-merge-algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-merge-algorithm)?
   2. Language-specific: corresponding [language-data-structure-name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/language-data-structure-name) is enough. Merging data structures is different in languages.
4. Merging files:  pick [merge-file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/merge-file) ([filemerge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/filemerge) is a software).
5. Merging images, audio/video streams: forbid. Question is always "merging in language A" or "merging with library B". If it's "merging with software C" — offtopic and move to SuperUser.
6. Any particular method/function called `merge()` from a particular library: forbid. Question header is enough.
7. Other usages: should be determined by experts in their fields. I've got no idea of what is a good replacement for questions about [json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/json) or [gis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gis). But usually general tag + "Merge A with B" in header should be enough.

Comment: Someone might want to merge [tag:filemerge] and [tag:merge-file] together, so we don't have to pick between two (probably badly named) tags.

Comment: Also, don't forget about the (often better) option to just removing [tag:merge] from questions if it doesn't add any value.

Comment: @KevinBrown If there's no better substitution, removing is certainly a preferred option. As for filemerge - yes, that's what I meant. Edited the answer about these tags.

Answer (score 3):

VCS-related:

This may not be related to a given SSCS, e.g. it may be about how to merge a visual studio project file.  Or even how to design your code so the merger is easier.

Also why not use the FileMerge and Git tag together instead of having a GitMerge tag....

Comment: [tag:git-merge] is not just about merging files. It's a particular Git command, which merges commits/branches using a very different concept. It may lead to merging files, but that's not equal.