# How generic are generics?

Tags: discussion, tags

I happened across a Haskell question relating to GHC generics that was tagged [generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/generics). Based on the description of that tag, I re-tagged it [ghc-generics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ghc-generics). I was just starting to re-tag other similar posts when I decided it might be better to check with Meta.

#### Pros

GHC generics are completely unrelated to the type system feature known as generics in object oriented languages, so using the same tag seems a bit odd. The tag description also goes with the OO sense.

#### Cons

It seems that somewhat more people asking questions about GHC generics reach for the generics tag than the ghc-generics one.

It seems likely that language features similar to GHC generics might exist in other languages as well, or might be added in time. If that is or becomes the case, then ghc-generics will be too narrow.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/293773/17034

Comment: Another tough one that comes to mind is "reflection", which means one thing in Haskell, one thing in Agda, and various other unrelated things elsewhere.

Comment: But, when combined with the language tag, all search results should be classified properly. A tag having a different meaning for different languages, does not mean that it is a bad tag. #[tag:for-loop]