# Why do we have [ajax-success] and [ajaxcomplete]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

Why do we have [ajax-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-success) and [ajaxcomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxcomplete)? Both refer to a method in jQuery that triggers a function in argument 1 on either a succesful ajax call or a completed ajax call.

I don't see the practical use of having such tags. Is there any situation where splitting up questions to use ajax-success/ajaxcomplete over [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery) [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) would be useful?

Can I burn them? With fire? Glorious, blazing fire?

Comment: No, you clean them out with [Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28cleaning_product%29).

Comment: Should I tag this question with [tag:ajaxify-request] instead then?

Comment: Sigh.  This happens when people don't pay attention [to this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297391/17034) and just do their own thing.

Comment: Unless some major complaint comes up, I'll probably retag both in 2 days time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have <s>burned</s> cleaned StackExchange's dirty surfaces with Ajax (tm) and now we have [no more questions](https://stackoverflow.com/?tags=ajaxcomplete%20ajaxstart%20ajaxstop%20ajax-success%20ajaxsetup) tagged with

- [ajaxcomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxcomplete)
- [ajax-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-success)
- [ajaxstop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxstop) (found this beauty on the way)
- [ajaxstart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxstart) (and this one)
- [ajaxsetup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxsetup) (and this one)

I tagged those questions with [ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax) (and [jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery)) where appropriate, and removed other shady tags where possible.

The order of things has been restored.

We can all now sleep happy now.

> Actually, not really. As it turns out we also have a tag [load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/load) which apparently should be used for cpu-load, but is used for whatever people want.

> We also have a [repeat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/repeat) for repeating things... Apparently we have users that are experts in repeating things. Who knew.

> We can earn our burinating [checkmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/checkmark)s

Comment: I'm cool with this, as long as [tag:success] does not return

Comment: Darn it. I wanted to create an infinite loop, turn that into energy and thus exploit retagging to power the world.

Comment: There isn't nearly enough caffeine in the world for that plan to work

Comment: It looks like there are 8 questions with [tag:ajax-success], 1 with [tag:ajaxcomplete], 1 with [tag:ajaxstop] and 3 with [tag:ajax-setup]. I threw a CV on most of the open ones fwiw

Comment: Yup. It looks like the new navigation is broken... -_-'

Comment: What about [tag:ajaxform]? No sleep for the weary...

Comment: That tag might be marginally useful, at least if it is used for the subject that is in the tag wiki. I recon that there might be experts who have worked with forms and ajax before that might follow the tag. It is at least broader than the function-tags I addressed above. I would suggest making a new Q&A if you would like to see [tag:ajaxform] gone.

Comment: [tag:ajax-success] was recreated? There's 26 posts now.

Comment: I have, once again, applied a flamethrower to the tag.

Answer (score 1):

I [retagged a couple hundred questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297634/1768232) from [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success) to [ajax-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajax-success) (and 11 questions to [magento-success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/magento-success) which already existed before I started doing it.

I don't really have a problem with burninating it; the good thing is that I substantially edited the decent ones and put close votes on the really bad ones so this should be an easy burnination.

I don't know anything about [ajaxcomplete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ajaxcomplete), I certainly didn't create it.