# So, if you could just go ahead and rename this tag, that would be [good]

Tags: support, tags, moderation

<sup><sub>Spoiler alert: [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) has been burned. As per Durron's comments, can it be blacklisted if appropriate?</sub></sup>

---

I stumbled upon the [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) tag today, as it has been used for a stream-of-consciousness tag set on a question. The tag itself is useful, as it's been applied for the *good* process monitor for *hapi* servers in all the other questions it's currently applied to, and the tag wiki reflects that. There are almost as many followers as there are questions. (4 & 5... not many, but still...)

However, it has the potential for abuse.

I suggest we rename the tag to [hapijs-good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs-good).

According to [How to rename a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/87437/how-to-rename-a-tag), we need a moderator to do that.

[image: So if you could just go ahead and do that...]

Comment: There are 5 questions with that tag, can't you just retag them and let the roomba clean up the other tag? After all that is what the linked question says to do if there are only a handful of tags

Comment: @JoeW Nope, there are subscribers who would be lost.

Comment: hit enter to soon but the linked question says to edit them yourself if there is just a handful of tags and from the way I read it they don't actually rename the tag but create a new one with the tool.

Comment: A tag with 5 questions and 5 followers needs a moderators limited time?

Comment: -1 for the tag in question not being [tag:great]

Comment: @JoeW - You might be right about interpreting the Meta answer like that. If the only benefit of the Mod tool is that it's automatic, then a manual retag makes sense.

Comment: Can you edit the question to add a request to blacklist the tag?

Comment: @durron597 Blacklisting a tag required developer intervention and system resources to enforce so it is not something to be done lightly

Comment: @JoeW I know that.

Comment: @durron597 - done, we'll see what happens when a mod gets around to marking this [tag:request-complete].

Comment: But now we don't have any [tag:good] questions! D=

Comment: @jpmc26 ...And how is that any different than any other day?

Comment: It's burned. I think you can accept an answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't agree. The [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) tag should be burninated; there is no need to have a **separate** tag for [hapijs-good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs-good).

The crappy question from the 10th has been deleted, and the other four questions are all already tagged [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs). Following the precedent from [other efforts like this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297714/why-do-we-have-ajax-success-and-ajaxcomplete), we should just burn and blacklist this tag entirely.

Comment: I love burning things. However, the tag isn't that old, with all its questions coming in the past 10 weeks or so, so we can expect there will be more over time (...can't predict the popularity of the service). It would be likely to come back - so providing a more abuse-proof option would be prudent.

Comment: @Mogsdad Sorry, I've added the words "and blacklist" to this answer.

Answer (score 20):

After more digging on [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) & [hapijs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hapijs):

- There are currently 65+ modules / plugins that are part of the project.
- NONE of them have their own tag prefixed by hapijs.
- I went through about 1/2 the existing hapijs questions, and saw no other module names used as tags.

Conclusion: [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) should burn. Done.