# In the name of [god]

Tags: discussion, tags, moderation

I was looking for things related to [good](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/good) after seeing [So, if you could just go ahead and rename this tag, that would be [good]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306149/so-if-you-could-just-go-ahead-and-rename-this-tag-that-would-be-good) and I stumbled upon [god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/god).  The excerpt states

> God is a Ruby process monitoring framework designed to keep processes up and running.

I think that we should rename [god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/god) to [ruby-god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-god) as, to me, the name is very ambiguous.

Comment: inb4 all the pun comments

Comment: In the name of [god], please rename this.

Comment: I wonder if there are 10 ruby-god command(ment)s.

Comment: And all these years I thought he was a celestial being.

Comment: Are there any agnostic uses of [god]? Also, does anyone just tag their question with [good]? (as in "Of course my question is _good_, can't you see the tag?")

Comment: [good] [god], what is with this tag name?

Comment: The tag with my favorite SO title ever: "Using God to monitor Unicorn" http://stackoverflow.com/q/3877178/306084

Comment: That's just awesome.

Comment: _kof kof_ [tag:devil] _kof_

Comment: I wonder if [tag:god] is the opposite of thdvl.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The relevant parts of [tag guidelines](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/) in this context are as follows:

> If the tag can't work as the only tag on a question [...]
>
> If the tag commonly means different things to different people [...]

Although these quotes are applied to the notion of "meta-tag", they correctly indicate features that we don't want in tags. The tag in question has them both:

- it can't work as the only tag on a question
- means different things to different people (even in the narrow programming context, e.g. the above-mentioned design anti-pattern)

Thus I agree it should be renamed.

Comment: [A tag not being able to be the only tag on a question is not enough](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/290894/1768232)

Comment: @durron597 I'm not claiming it's enough - that's why I've given more than one reason.

Comment: Yay!  No more inviting people to confuse "meta" and "ambiguous"

Answer (score 22):

[There are a lot of people out there that think of this as "god".](https://rubygems.org/gems/god)  I don't mean that in a sacrilegious way, either; that's just what a *lot* of people understand this gem's name to be.

I'm in favor of renaming it, but I would imagine that we'd want a synonym linking back to [god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/god), *just in case* someone wants to ask a question about it but doesn't realize that it's actually tagged as something else.

Comment: *how many people outside of Ruby userbase* think that "god" in programming context would mean a gem's name? Hint 1: not many. Hint 2: that's "a lot of Ruby users", not "a lot of people". http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html ; https://github.com/blog/2047-language-trends-on-github ; http://www.sitepoint.com/best-programming-language-learn-2014/ ; Ruby users are "some people", but hardly "a lot of people" in the sense "majority of the people", mind me. If `god` was a *n*x shell command or Java system library component - I'd agree. As for Ruby - I don't.

Comment: Right.  So let's assume the context of "people" refers to Ruby developers...

Comment: I wouldn't assume that, because it would contradict your main point of leaving it as a synonim - the fact that "a lot of Ruby developers" understands or considers something doesn't imply that a *common SO user* does so also; general SO tags ain't meant *for Ruby developers* - they are meant *for all developers*. I'm not saying that a [god] tag is wrong by itself - it ain't; it's just that the potential for abuse here is IMO way too high vs the actual benefit that leaving such synonim would provide.

Answer (score 16):

There's no sign of ambiguity in the tag. Out of 110 questions tagged [god](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/god), only 21 are without [ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby) or [ruby-on-rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails), and even they are obviously talking about the god gem. There's no unrelated use of the tag, such as talking about the god object anti-pattern.

Unless there's a problem caused by this tag, such as the site being blocked in theocracies, or reasonable users finding it offensive, we should leave it as-is.

Comment: only 21?   That's roughly 20%!

Comment: @Joe if you regard the tag name as offensive, post that as an question or an answer, not as a comment.

Comment: @Bron thanks for reading the entirety of my post.