# show more comment link broken

Tags: bug, status-norepro, comments

I just came across this post [In the name of [god]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306155/in-the-name-of-god?cb=1) which leads me to  [Using God to monitor Unicorn - Start exited with non-zero code = 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877178/using-god-to-monitor-unicorn-start-exited-with-non-zero-code-1)  where you can see *`show 1 more comment`* link which is broken!

may be there is too much unicorn and god!!

Comment: Interesting: the request works correctly but the response is empty...

Comment: This has happened many times for me. I thought the comments were deleted.

Comment: Reproduced earlier. Can't seem to reproduce it now. Seems to be [meta-tag:status-completed]

Comment: Reproduced today, see [pragmatic solution](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/397289/2932052)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A mod recently purged all comments on that question, so if you were seeing any comments at all you were seeing a cached page. The ajax request was requesting actual data, which didn't contain any comments at all.

Conclusion: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/