# Strange ghost comment

Tags: bug

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35906678/1392132) seems to have two comments on it, only one of which is shown to me.

> [image]

The strange thing is that no matter how often I try clicking on the “show 1 more comment” link, the second comment disappears.

> [image]

When I refresh the page, the behavior can be reproduced consistently.

I am using Firefox 44.0.2 for GNU/Linux with the LXDE desktop. What is going on here?

Comment: Can reproduce in both browser and cURL. Nothing showing in the timeline: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/35906678/timeline

Comment: I have half a mind to add a comment and see what happens, but that might destroy the evidence of the bug.

Comment: @Alexander O'Mara: Oh, great. Now I'm tempted to lock the post temporarily just so people don't go touching anything. But then by locking the post *I'd* be touching it. So I guess all I can do is say ***NOBODY TOUCH ANYTHING***

Comment: @BoltClock Somebody has just added another comment and that apparently broke the quantum entanglement. I'm glad you've looked at it so quickly.

Comment: @5gon12eder: Oh well. At least it was the asker and not somebody else possibly from meta.

Comment: @HansPassant Seems like a plausible duplicate. Since the link in that question no longer shows the problem, I'm hesitant to confirm it right away, though. I'll wait for others to confirm this is the same issue.

Comment: This happens to me all the time since I'll open a bunch of questions at once from my front page in new tabs. I thought it was just trying to view deleted comments.

Comment: @5gon12eder It's the same issue. I saw that post when it went up, I can confirm it.

Comment: @MageXy It's definitely not a client-side caching issue. The phenomenon persisted over browser re-starts (which is configured to clear all history and offline data).

Comment: @Kendra Alright then. Thanks for confirming.

Answer (score 13):

For what it's worth, there is a comment from another user that was posted shortly after the first, and self-deleted several minutes later. This comment shows up as a deleted comment everywhere a moderator can access deleted comments. It might very well be the "1 more comment", but I have no idea why that prompt is still there long after the comment was deleted.

Or it might not have been, in which case I blame cosmic rays.

Comment: It couldn't possibly have been ghosts, unicorns, or narwhals...

Comment: /sings: _Comments, comments listed on your question. Messin' up your session, 'cause they are so awesome..._

Comment: We found another one, one that *noone can touch* (*ha ha, can't touch it!*). 10k only: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30802718. There is a deleted comment there, deleted when I destroyed a spammer account.

Comment: Shouldn't we rather blame caching (of comment counts)?

Comment: This has actually [happened](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306333/show-more-comment-link-broken) a couple times [before.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306333/show-more-comment-link-broken) That second one has an "official" "caching" answer. :)

Comment: Mommy, the cosmic rays ate my comment!