# Blacklisting is the key to [success]

Tags: support, tags, blocklist-request

We have already *successfully burninated* [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success).

- [Burninate? Great [success]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286423/)
- [Do we want [success]?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297388/)

[image: Giant spider web flamethrower]

Because of the *concept* of

- [An operation completing successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8514550/payment-success)
- [A project or concept working successfully](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655720/what-are-success-factors-in-software-development-projects)
- [A success page loading (in response to a form)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19488660/show-succes-message-when-user-clicks-registration-verification-link)
- [Ajax's deprecated success callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472474/ajax-no-succes-action-taken)
- [Magento's success page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963818/magento-newsletter-success-messages-in-js-prompt)

All of which could inspire the tag to come back again, but none are really appropriate to be contained in a tag.

## Let's blacklist [success](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/success) too.

Comment: Fancy gif. But are you sure you want a mad person going around burning tags? (Like the gif) Because flamethrowers are dangerous weapons

Comment: @UniKitty, flamethrowers are a joke. We have [far more dangerous weapons](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121570/i-made-us-some-trogdor-graphics) at our disposal.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I think the most dangerous is __Mod Abuse__!

Comment: @UniKitty, I don't know that meme. Is it new? :)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi [Perhaps](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/22205106#22205106)...